# Is reading data in one thread while it is written to in another dangerous for the OS?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

There is nothing in the way the program uses this data which will cause the program to crash if it reads the old value rather than the new value. It **will** get the new value at some point.

However, I am wondering if reading and writing at the same time from multiple threads can cause problems for the OS?

I am yet to see them if it does. The program is developed in Linux using pthreads.

I am not interested in being told how to use mutexs/semaphores/locks/etc **edit:** so my program is only getting the new values, that is not what I'm asking.

Comment: I thought I'd add that the data in question is within an array. There is only one thread reading that array. There are multiple threads writing to the array but each is only writing to a unique subset of the array.

Comment: Mutexs are used to determine which unique subset of the array each thread fills.

Comment: And like I said, **there are no problems to the program regarding inconsistencies between old/new/partial values written**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.. the OS should not have any problem. The tipical problem is the that you dont want to read the old values or a value that is half way updated, and thus not valid (and may crash your app or if the next value depends on the former, then you can get a corrupted value and keep generating wrong values all the itme), but if you dont care about that, the OS wont either.

Answer (score 2):

Are the kernel/drivers reading that data for any reason (eg. it contains structures passed in to kernel APIs)? If no, then there isn't any issue with it, since the OS will never ever look at your hot memory.

Your own reads must ensure they are consistent so you don't read half of a value pre-update and half post-update and end up with a value that is neither pre neither post update.

Answer (score 2):

There is no danger for the OS. Only your program's data integrity is at risk.

Imagine you data to consist of a set (structure) of values, which cannot be updated in an atomic operation. The reading thread is bound to read inconsistent data at some point (data consisting of a mixture of old and new values). But you did not want to hear about mutexes...

Comment: See my edits/comments re-emphasising the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Problems arise when multiple threads share access to data when accessing that data is not atomic. For example, imagine a struct with 10 interdependent fields. If one thread is writing and one is reading, the reading thread is likely to see a struct that is halfway between one state and another (for example, half of it's members have been set).

If on the other hand the data can be read and written to with a single atomic operation, you will be fine. For example, imagine if there is a global variable that contains a count... One thread is incrementing it on some condition, and another is reading it and taking some action... In this case, there is really no intermediate inconsistent state. It's either got the new value, or it has the old value.

Logically, you can think of locking as a tool that lets you make arbitrary blocks of code atomic, at least as far as the other threads of execution are concerned.